Yosemite national park availability
I am traveling to the USA end of August. We are planning to visit Yosemite national park on the 31th of August. However, already now, tickets are not available and all lodging specifically for that day are not available, while the day beforehand there is still lodging. Is there some kind of event happening? I've looked around but I can't find anything.


The calendar in your picture says not yet released. Is that different information than the availability you mention?

"the day beforehand there is still lodging". 30th August is unavailable, as are weekdays from 19th. The rest of the month is available.

"Is there some kind of event happening?"   Aug 31, 2024 is the Saturday before US Labor Day.   That makes it the start of a very popular 3-day-weekend for folks to camp and travel.

The weekdays in the last two weeks of August are not available because that is after peak season and reservations are not required.
The weekend date August 31st is not available because those tickets have not yet been released. They will be released on August 24th.
From the National Park Service website:

A reservation is required to drive into or through Yosemite National Park on some days from April 13 through October 27, 2024, for those driving into the park between 5 am and 4 pm as follows:

April 13 through June 30: A reservation is required from 5 am to 4 pm on Saturdays, Sundays, and on holidays (May 27 and June 19). A reservation is not required on other days.
July 1 through August 16: A reservation is required from 5 am to 4 pm every day.
August 17 through October 27: A reservation is required from 5 am to 4 pm on Saturdays, Sundays, and holidays (September 2 and October 14). A reservation is not required on other days.


From the recreation.gov reservation website, if you hover over August 31st, the tooltip says:

Next release: Aug 24, 2024 at 08:00 am PDT

If you click on August 31, you get these images that show that the tickets were released for the first time on Jan 5, 2024, and another batch will release one week before the desired date.

